# window.opener reference is changed during redirect from Applet in Java 1.7.0_04-b20 but not in 1.7.0_03-b05

Tags: java, javascript, firefox, applet, popup

I ran into an issue with the javascript property `window.opener` (which keeps a reference to the window that opened the popup) in conjunction with a redirect from within an applet. Whenever a redirect happens from within the applet, `window.opener` was changed to the current pop-up. Even stranger is the fact that this change was introduced with a recent java update quite recently: this did not happen with `java 1.7.0_03-b05` but started happening with `java 1.7.0_04-b20`. Now this might be some exotic usecase but still, I'm wondering if this change was intentional.

To get to the bottom of this I have written a small test to demonstrate the behavior in question. The HTML-Sites can be found [here](http://files.newsnetz.ch/applet_test). It does only work in Firefox (which is OK for my usecase)

1. The `index.html` page contains the following javascript:

   ```
   window.name = "index.html";

   function open_new_window() {
       window.open('applet.html', 'applet.html', 'width=1050,height=680,scrollbars=yes,status=yes').focus();
       return false;
   }
   ```

   I set the windows name to "index.html" (for identification purpose) and provide a function that will open applet.html in a popup-window.
   It also contains a link which calls this function:

   ```
   <a href="#" onclick="open_new_window(); return false;">open applet.html in new                
   window</a>
   ```
2. after clicking the link, `applet.html` is opened in a popup. This contains the following javascript:

   ```
   window.name = "HelloWorldApplet.html";

   alert("opener is now: "+window.opener.name);

   function on_load() {
       alert("changing bgcolor of opener to red");
       window.opener.document.body.style.background='red';
   }
   ```

   I set this popup's window.name to "applet.html" (for identification purpose) and alert the current `window.opener.name`. When the body fires the onload event, I change the openers background color to red.

   Also, this page contains an applet, which has a button that will fire a redirect to `redirect.html`

   ```
   import java.applet.Applet;
   import java.awt.Button;
   import java.awt.FlowLayout;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
   import java.net.MalformedURLException;
   import java.net.URL;
   import java.util.logging.Level;
   import java.util.logging.Logger;

   public class HelloWorldApplet extends Applet implements ActionListener {

       Button redirectButton;

       @Override
       public void init() {
           super.init();

           setLayout(new FlowLayout());
           redirectButton = new Button("Redirect now!");
           add(redirectButton);

           redirectButton.addActionListener(this);
       }

       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
           try {
               this.getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL(this.getDocumentBase(), "redirect.html"), "_self");
           } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldApplet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. after clicking the button in the applet, `redirect.html` is opened in the same popup-window. This page contains the following javascript:

   ```
   window.name = "redirect.html";

   alert("opener is now: "+window.opener.name);
   function on_load() {
       alert("changing bgcolor of opener to green");
       window.opener.document.body.style.background='green';
   }
   ```

   I set this popup's window.name to "redirect.html" (for identification purpose) and alert the current `window.opener.name`. When the body fires the onload event, I change the openers background color to green.

With `java 1.7.0_03-b5` the following happens:

1. After clicking the link in `index.html`, `applet.html` is opened in a popup window. The alert shows `index.html` as being the openers name. Then the backgroundcolor of the opener is changed to red
2. After clicking the button in the applet `redirect.html` is opened in the same window. The alert shows `index.html`as being the openers name. Then the backgroundcolor of the opener is changed to green

so far so good... but with `java 1.7.0_04-b20` the following happens:

1. After clicking the link in `index.html`, `applet.html` is opened in a popup window. The alert shows `index.html` as being the openers name. Then the backgroundcolor of the opener is changed to red
2. After clicking the button in the applet `redirect.html` is opened in the same window. The alert shows 'redirect.html` as being the openersname. Then the backgroundcolor of the opener (which is the popup-window now!) is changed to green.

So it seems the redirect issued by the Applet via `this.getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL(this.getDocumentBase(), "redirect.html"), "_self");` changes the window.opener property to the window it changed the URL in...

I would appreciate any insights into why this behavior might have changed or if you could imagine a workaround to this problem.

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Consider using a [draggable applet](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/6u10_applets/) instead.  Note that most people will not especially care about yet another applet / JS / browser / JRE / focus - interaction bug or quirk.  The only advice the top applet answerer can muster at this time is as follows.  Stop pissing about with multiple browser windows.  If you do, the pain is well deserved.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the comment and 'advice'. I wish i could 'stop pissing about with multiple browser windows' but as it is right now this decision is out of my hands.

Comment: *"right now this decision is out of my hands"*  Please assure me that you are charging 'top dollar' from whoever made the decision. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post helped me understand that I'm not the only one going crazy here. I believe this is a bug in the new java version.

I simply added the following javascript to my popup page:

var parentWin = window.opener;

then, when I need to call the parent, I use parentWin. This solved my problem.

Comment: yeah, seems to be a bug! http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7187791